# I need to extract some data using python from a html page

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is part of a html page from which i need to extract the following items:
name from the strong tag, classification type (Actor and Singer), born and died location.

```
<li class="clearfix">
   <div style="margin-top:10px;">
      <div class="float-left" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
         <a href="http://" title="Elvis Presley" name="Elvis Presley" class="float-left">
         <strong>Mr. Elvis Presley</strong></a>
      </div>
      <div class="rating_overall fleft" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
         <div class="rating_overall voted_rating_overall" style='width:72.96px;'></div>
      </div>
      <span class="result-vote float-left" id="result" style="line-height:15px; color: #AAA; font-size: 0.9em; margin-top: 1px;"> &nbsp; (15 vots)</span>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <a href="http://" title="Mr. Elvis Presley" name="Mr. Elvis Presley">
      <img style="float:left;" src="http://a.jpg" alt="Mr. Elvis Presley" title="Mr. Elvis Presley"  />
      </a>
      <br/>
      <p>
         <b>Classification:</b>
         <a href="http://" title="Actor " name="Actor " class="underline">Actor </a>
         ,                      <a href="" title="Singer" name="Singer" class="underline">Singer</a>
         <br />
         <b>Born:</b> <a href="http://" title="Tupelo" name="Tupelo" class="underline">Tupelo</a><br />
         <b>Died:</b>
         Memphis,
         <!--<b>City:</b>-->
         <a href="http://" title="Memphis" name="Memphis" class="underline">Memphis</a>
      </p>
      <div class="clk"></div>
   </div>
</li>
```

I had try using the BeautifulSoup but i'm a newbie on python :

```
    data2 = soup.find_all('li',{'class':'clearfix'})

for container in data2:
    if container.find('a', {'class':'float-left'}):
        name = container.a.text
        print (name)

    if container.find('a', {'class':'underline'}):
        classification=container.div.p.a.text
        print (classification)


flag
```

Although I didn't get any errors from the script, I managed to extract only the name and the first classification. How do I target the rest of the elements that I need: classification("Singer") and the born and died location?

Comment: Do you get errors? If so, edit your question and add the errors. If the problem is something else, then describe it. IOW, what does your program do when you run it?

Comment: I didn't get errors.I managed to extract only the name and the first classification.How do i target the rest of the elements that i need: classification("Singer") and the born and died location?

Comment: Why don't you `find_all(class_='underline')` and select 0,1,2,3 ?

Comment: Can you please give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: @florin check out my updated answer , I have updated answer for beautifulsoup as you wanted, If that solve you issue you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use beautiful soup for html parser , I am showing you both first with beautiful soup and second  with regex and catch the results with group capturing :

> First with Beautiful soup:

```
string_1="""<li class="clearfix">
   <div style="margin-top:10px;">
      <div class="float-left" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
         <a href="http://" title="Elvis Presley" name="Elvis Presley" class="float-left">
         <strong>Mr. Elvis Presley</strong></a>
      </div>
      <div class="rating_overall fleft" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
         <div class="rating_overall voted_rating_overall" style='width:72.96px;'></div>
      </div>
      <span class="result-vote float-left" id="result" style="line-height:15px; color: #AAA; font-size: 0.9em; margin-top: 1px;"> &nbsp; (15 vots)</span>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <a href="http://" title="Mr. Elvis Presley" name="Mr. Elvis Presley">
      <img style="float:left;" src="http://a.jpg" alt="Mr. Elvis Presley" title="Mr. Elvis Presley"  />
      </a>
      <br/>
      <p>
         <b>Classification:</b>
         <a href="http://" title="Actor " name="Actor " class="underline">Actor </a>
         ,                      <a href="" title="Singer" name="Singer" class="underline">Singer</a>
         <br />
         <b>Born:</b> <a href="http://" title="Tupelo" name="Tupelo" class="underline">Tupelo</a><br />
         <b>Died:</b>
         Memphis,
         <!--<b>City:</b>-->
         <a href="http://" title="Memphis" name="Memphis" class="underline">Memphis</a>
      </p>
      <div class="clk"></div>
   </div>
</li>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(string_1,"html.parser")
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(a['name'])
```

Output:

```
Elvis Presley
Mr. Elvis Presley
Actor 
Singer
Tupelo
Memphis
```

> Second with regex:

Use it if the form code is same as you shown there :

```
import re
string_1="""<li class="clearfix">
   <div style="margin-top:10px;">
      <div class="float-left" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
         <a href="http://" title="Elvis Presley" name="Elvis Presley" class="float-left">
         <strong>Mr. Elvis Presley</strong></a>
      </div>
      <div class="rating_overall fleft" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
         <div class="rating_overall voted_rating_overall" style='width:72.96px;'></div>
      </div>
      <span class="result-vote float-left" id="result" style="line-height:15px; color: #AAA; font-size: 0.9em; margin-top: 1px;"> &nbsp; (15 vots)</span>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <a href="http://" title="Mr. Elvis Presley" name="Mr. Elvis Presley">
      <img style="float:left;" src="http://a.jpg" alt="Mr. Elvis Presley" title="Mr. Elvis Presley"  />
      </a>
      <br/>
      <p>
         <b>Classification:</b>
         <a href="http://" title="Actor " name="Actor " class="underline">Actor </a>
         ,                      <a href="" title="Singer" name="Singer" class="underline">Singer</a>
         <br />
         <b>Born:</b> <a href="http://" title="Tupelo" name="Tupelo" class="underline">Tupelo</a><br />
         <b>Died:</b>
         Memphis,
         <!--<b>City:</b>-->
         <a href="http://" title="Memphis" name="Memphis" class="underline">Memphis</a>
      </p>
      <div class="clk"></div>
   </div>
</li>"""
pattern=r'<strong>(\w.+)<\/strong>|<b>Classification:<\/b>(\s.+)(\s.+)|(Born:.+)|(Died:.+\s.+\s.+\s.+)'
pattern_2=r'name=["](\w.+?)["]'


match=re.finditer(pattern,string_1,re.M)
for find in match:
    if find.group(1):
        print("Name {}".format(find.group(1)))
    if find.group(2):
        print("Classificiation first {}".format(re.search(pattern_2,str(find.group(2))).group(1)))
        print("Classification second {}".format(re.search(pattern_2,str(find.group(3))).group(1)))
    if find.group(4):
        print("Born {}".format(re.search(pattern_2, str(find.group(4))).group(1)))
    if find.group(5):
        print("Dead {}".format(re.search(pattern_2, str(find.group(5))).group(1)))
```

output:

```
Name Mr. Elvis Presley
Classificiation first Actor 
Classification second Singer
Born Tupelo
Dead Memphis
```

Comment: In general, regexes are *not* recommended for parsing HTML (among other things). The OP (actually all of us) is better off with a proper parser.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick!Can you please give me a hint how to target the rest of 3 elements?

Comment: @Nick i have added both method with BS html parser and with regex.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul But if I have more li tags containing the same elements how do I search in all of them?

Comment: @florin first find_all 'li' .